# Best way to do binary arithmetic in C?

Tags: c, binary, performance, math, processing-efficiency

I am learning C and writing a simple program that will take 2 string values assumed to each be binary numbers and perform an arithmetic operation according to user selection:

- Add the two values,
- Subtract input 2 from input 1, or
- Multiply the two values.

My implementation assumes each character in the string is a binary bit, e.g. `char bin5 = "0101";`, but it seems too naive an approach to parse through the string a character at a time. Ideally, I would want to work with the binary values directly.

What is the most efficient way to do this in C? Is there a better way to treat the input as binary values rather than `scanf()` and get each bit from the string?

I did some research but I didn't find any approach that was obviously better from the perspective of a beginner. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Advice:**
There's not much that's obviously better than marching through the string a character at a time and making sure the user entered only ones and zeros.  Keep in mind that even though you could write a *really* fast assembly routine if you **assume** everything is `1` or `0`, you don't really want to do that.  The user could enter anything, and you'd like to be able to tell them if they screwed up or not.

It's true that this seems mind-bogglingly slow compared to the couple cycles it probably takes to add the actual numbers, but does it really matter if you get your answer in a nanosecond or a millisecond?  Humans can only detect 30 milliseconds of latency anyway.

Finally, it already takes far longer to get input from the user and write output to the screen than it does to parse the string or add the numbers, so your algorithm is hardly the bottleneck here.  Save your fancy optimizations for things that are actually computationally intensive :-).

What you should focus on here is making the task less manpower-intensive.  And, it turns out someone already did that for you.

**Solution:**
Take a look at [the `strtol()` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

```
long strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

This will let you convert a string (nptr) in any base to a long.  It checks errors, too.  Sample usage for converting a binary string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char buf[MAX_BUF];
get_some_input(buf);

char *err;
long number = strtol(buf, &err, 2);
if (*err) {
    // bad input: try again?
} else {
    // number is now a long converted from a valid binary string.
}
```

Supplying base 2 tells `strtol` to convert binary literals.

Comment: Negative binary number strings are unusual, so you probably want to use strtoul(3)

Answer (score 4):

First out I do recommend that you use stuff like strtol as recommended by tgamblin, 
it's better to use things that the lib gives to you instead of creating the wheel over and over again.

But since you are learning C I did a little version without strtol, 
it's neither fast or safe but I did play a little with the bit manipulation as a example.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int data = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char str[] = "1001";

    char* pos;
    pos = &str[strlen(str)-1];

    while(*pos == '0' || *pos == '1')
    {
        (*pos) -= '0';
        data += (*pos) << i;

        i++;
        pos--;
    }

    printf("data %d\n", data);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the best performance, you need to distinguish between trusted and untrusted input to your functions.

For example, a function like `getBinNum()` which accepts input from the user should be checked for valid characters and compressed to remove leading zeroes. First, we'll show a general purpose in-place compression function:

```
// General purpose compression removes leading zeroes.
void compBinNum (char *num) {
    char *src, *dst;

    // Find first non-'0' and move chars if there are leading '0' chars.
    for (src = dst = num; *src == '0'; src++);
    if (src != dst) {
        while (*src != '\0')
            *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst = '\0';
    }

    // Make zero if we removed the last zero.
    if (*num == '\0')
            strcpy (num, "0");
}
```

Then provide a checker function that returns either the passed in value, or NULL if it was invalid:

```
// Check untested number, return NULL if bad.
char *checkBinNum (char *num) {
    char *ptr;

    // Check for valid number.
    for (ptr = num; *ptr == '0'; ptr++)
        if ((*ptr != '1') && (*ptr != '0'))
            return NULL;

    return num;
}
```

Then the input function itself:

```
#define MAXBIN 256

// Get number from (untrusted) user, return NULL if bad.
char *getBinNum (char *prompt) {
    char *num, *ptr;

    // Allocate space for the number.
    if ((num = malloc (MAXBIN)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Get the number from the user.
    printf ("%s: ", prompt);
    if (fgets (num, MAXBIN, stdin) == NULL) {
        free (num);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Remove newline if there.
    if (num[strlen (num) - 1] == '\n')
        num[strlen (num) - 1] = '\0';

    // Check for valid number then compress.
    if (checkBinNum (num) == NULL) {
        free (num);
        return NULL;
    }
    compBinNum (num);

    return num;
}
```

Other functions to add or multiply should be written to assume the input is already valid since it will have been created by one of the functions in this library. I won't provide the code for them since it's not relevant to the question:

```
char *addBinNum (char *num1, char *num2) {...}
char *mulBinNum (char *num1, char *num2) {...}
```

If the user chooses to source their data from somewhere other than `getBinNum()`, you could allow them to call `checkBinNum()` to validate it.

If you were really paranoid, you could check every number passed in to your routines and act accordingly (return NULL), but that would require relatively expensive checks that aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to parse the strings into integers, and then perform your maths on the integers?

I'm assuming this is a school assignment, but i'm upvoting you because you appear to be giving it a good effort.

Comment: This is in fact what I did. Since I couldn't find a way to represent numbers in a binary radix in a numeric datatype (unlike hex's 0xFF), I am performing operations on decimal numbers and converting back to binary values.

Origins of my question are related to an assignment, but that is done now.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that a string is a binary number simply because it consists only of digits from the set {0,1} is dangerous. For example, when your input is "11", the user may have meant eleven in decimal, not three in binary. It is this kind of carelessness that gives rise to horrible bugs. Your input is ambiguously incomplete and you should really request that the user specifies the base too.

Comment: PS. Normally when people see or type 11, they are far more likely to mean eleven than three and old habits die hard.

Comment: A good point. If I was making a generic-use script, allowing the user to select a radix of choice would be ideal to reduce input errors. In this particular use-case, it was well-established that binary values only would be used for input. That said, it is best to allow for specificity in cases where input ambiguity is possible.